# Problema con Appium: appium Original error: Activity name

Tags: android-studio, appium

Intento realizar test de una aplicación móvil con Appium y me está siendo imposible debido a que siempre que lo lanzo me retorna este error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.xxx.xxx' application. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.xxx.xxx' application. Consider checking the driver's troubleshooting documentation. Original error: Activity name '.com.xxx.xxx.architecture.views.activities.contexts.login.LogigActivity}' used to start the app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity
```

Me ocurre desde que cambié la versión beta de Android Studio por la última estable, ya que la beta me daba muchos problemas.

Para dar un poco más de información mis capabilities son:

```
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Pixel 6 API 33");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "android");
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.xxx.xxx");
            capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.xxx.xxx.architecture.views.activities.contexts.login.LoginActivity");
            capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UIAutomator2");
```

He intentado también añadir las capabilities appWaitPackage y appWaitActivity y el resultado es el mismo.
¿Alguna idea?